# Update Scene from Thread?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I need to update a `QGraphicsView` with a `QGraphicsScene` from a thread.

Below is some pseudo'ish code example of what I am doing which is causing me issues (runtime errors).

What am I doing wrong, and how should I be doing it?

Main App:

```
void Main::startThread()
{
  view = new QGraphicsView(...);
  thread = new MyThread(...);
  connect(thread, SIGNAL(doSceneUpdate(QGraphicsScene*)), this, SLOT(updateScene(QGraphicsScene*)));
  thread->start();
}

void Main::updateScene(QGraphicsScene *scene)
{
  view->SetScene(scene);
  view->show();
  repaint();
}
```

The Thread:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(...);
  while(1)
  {
    //draw stuff on the scene
    emit doSceneUpdate(scene);
    //some delay
  }
```

Thanks in advance!!!

[edit]
The error is:

```
ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread
3e53c0. Receiver '' (of type 'QGraphicsScene') was created in thread 1476cd18", file c:\Qt\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2\src\corelib\kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 501
```

Comment: What is the run-time error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong, and how should I be doing it?

I think the canonical answer is [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) -- in a nutshell, the article states that you shouldn't be subclassing QThread, but rather you should use a "bare" (i.e. not-subclassed) QThread object and connect its started() signal to a slot that will then be run in the context of that thread, after the thread starts.  That way the object-thread-ownership issues are handled automatically for you.

Note also that threads other than the main Qt thread are generally not allowed to create or interact directly with GUI objects like QGraphicsScene, since doing that would introduce race conditions due to the operations going on simultaneously behind the scenes in Qt's GUI event loop.  If you want to use a separate thread, you'll need to keep it away from your GUI objects, and instead just have it emit asynchronous signals and/or send Events to the main/GUI thread to get the main/GUI thread to do the GUI-object updates on its behalf.

Comment: Yeah, after more investigation ive changed the way the thread works somewhat. Doing so has introduced other problems though which ill ask about in another topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your connection line. You are connecting a slot to a signal which does not make sense. You should connect the signal from the thread to the slot :

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(doSceneUpdate(QGraphicsScene*)),this, SLOT(updateScene(QGraphicsScene*)));
```

Comment: My apologies.

I wrote the example code from memory, and did get those the wrong way around.
In my real source, they are the correct way around. I have fixed my example.

Answer (score 1):

in

```
void MyThread::run()
{
  QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(...);
  ...

}
```

do you pass `this` to the constructor of `QGraphicsScene()`?

That could be one cause of error, since now you are passing a child of `MyThread` to `Main`

Try creating a QGraphicsScene object on the stack or with the parent as NULL ( `new QGraphicsScene(0)` )

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It doesnt look like this is the problem as the actual code looks like:
scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, LCD_WIDTH, LCD_HEIGHT);