# Qt error - Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread,that is corrected by MouseTracking

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am programming with `Graphics View Framework`. I use a customized class which inherit from `QGraphicsView` to show `QGraphicsScene`. I new `QGraphicsScene` in main thread and new `QGraphicsItem` in another thread. When I call `scene.addItem()`--here QT will emit signal to scene and it is not allowed by QT. But if I write `setMouseTracking(true)` in my `QGraphicsView` that would correct the QT's error. Why?

My code:

```
//centralWidget.cpp
pGraphicsScene_ = new QGraphicsScene(this);
pMonitorView_ = new MonitorView(pGraphicsScene_);

//monitorView.cpp
MonitorView::MonitorView(QGraphicsScene *scene, QWidget *parent):
        QGraphicsView(scene, parent)
{
    setMouseTracking(true);//If I comment this line,will get error--for this I don't confuse but write this statement will correct error!
}

//another thread start by std::thread
pItem = new GoodsItem();
pGraphicsScene_->addItem(pItem);
```

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: Using GUI objects in different threads is not supported in Qt.

Comment: Not an answer, but instead of using `std::thread`  you might want to use `QThread` since it is designed to deal better with QT signals, [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284850/qthread-vs-stdthread). 

Apart from that, what is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @thuga You could misunderstand what I mean, you may need read my title.

Comment: @GertWollny This should be a error as title. But when I add `setMouseTracking(true);`, there is no error.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand. According to your code, you are using `QGraphicsScene` object in a different thread. This is not supported by Qt. The fact that the error goes away when you add `setMouseTracking(true)` is irrelevant. You are still doing something that you shouldn't be doing. See the second paragraph of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764337/2257050).

Comment: @Crawl.W Accurding to [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html)  signals can be send across threads, and maybe `setMouseTracking` sets up some threading related stuff that otherwise is missing (because std::thread does no QT related things), and hence the error message does no longer appear.   I'm not a QT expert, but I think "using GUI objects in different threads not supported" only  applies to drawing stuff in parallel, but to get things truly right you might have to add locking, which means that with a certain setup Qt will no longer issue an error but may still crash.

Comment: @GertWollny No, it doesn't apply only to drawing stuff in parallel. See [this documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy).

Comment: @thuga Yes,I know. But I am confused of reason that the error goes away.

Comment: And GertWollny is your meaning.To GertWollny, moreover, set mouse tracking and the program run very well.